# Select row from a table if a field is a substring of a field in another table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to understand why the following query is not working.

My schema:

```
CREATE TABLE category
    (`id` int, `category_name` varchar(55))
;

CREATE TABLE product
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(55), `categories` varchar(50))
;

CREATE TABLE product_categories
    (`id` int, `product` int, `category` int)
;

INSERT INTO category
    (`id`, `category_name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Home'),
    (2, 'Design')
;

INSERT INTO product
    (`id`, `name`, `categories`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Magazine', 'Home/Design/Interior'),
    (2, 'Book', 'Internet/Technology')
;
```

The query:

```
SELECT
category.id
FROM category
JOIN product
ON product.categories LIKE CONCAT('%' + category.category_name + '%')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3119/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

```
SELECT
category.id
FROM category
JOIN product
ON product.categories LIKE CONCAT('%' + category.category_name + '%');
```

and it should look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM category
JOIN product
ON product.categories LIKE CONCAT('%', category.category_name, '%');
```

`CONCAT()` is a function and the arguments to the function are separated by comma rather than `+`.

Comment: How would I go about inserting rows into the product_categories table for each product with matching category? For product with id 1 I would want two rows in "product_categories" with product = 1 and category =1 as well as product = 1 and category = 1.

Comment: Hmmm... Why does that sound like a new question? :-)